# Build error for xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker, linker-errors, xcode9

Since I updated `xcode` to `xcode9` I am getting build failure error just for simulators which is

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

In my project settings `Enable Bitcode:NO`, `active architecture:armv7`,`armv7s`,a`rm64`
and I've tried to delete derived data, also cleaned the project but that did not solve problem.

Any suggestion?

Comment: When i try to debug on real device everthing is fine. But in simulator i got build failure error.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning normally works for me. Have you tried deleting the app from the simulator and installing it again?

Whilst in the simulator select "iOS Simulator" then "Reset Content and Settings"

Comment: Thanks for answer but your suggestion did not solve the problem on simulator. @ThrowingSpoon